# What is the correct way to abstract a variable in an MSAccess VBA application?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 app that I have several variables in that I would like to move to some sort of configuration file. (like an app.config or web.conf) Is there an equivalent in Access?

Comment: Have you considered a table?

Comment: Well actually the value that I want to store is the connection string to the linked sql Tables. I would rather not keep tables in the Access DB itself for security reasons.

Comment: Best keep it in code, then.

Comment: Ouch that kinda defeats the dev/test/production process and environment that we use for all of our development. Thanks

Comment: What do you see as the difference between a string in a table and a string in a config file? They are both readable. Assign the string to a global variable, test if a connection exists, if not create a connection, yesno?

Comment: Except that I can change the string in the config file without making changes to the actual DB. If I make changes to a table in the DB then it is no longer the same across environments. Not that big of a deal but part of our deployment policies and in my opinion good practice.

Comment: Yea digging into that now. Thanks

Comment: As an aside, I would always put connection strings in code for security reasons.